# Azure Table Storage Date Sorted Reports

Tags: azure-table-storage

Is there a fast way to get the lowest valued partition key? I'm trying to create a table that is ordered by date. It will be for displaying reports on posts in an admin page. It can't be in an sql table because it has the potential to be billions of rows. I want each partition to represent a page and have 50 rows in it. I'll do some calculations to get the right partition. I think I may end up having some partition called "pages" with a blank row key and store the number of pages there. Using that I'll be able to get the partition key but if there's a built in way to do this I'd like to use that. I'm not too sure if I can make updating the "pages" partition while adding a new partition a transaction which could cause conflicts if things are added to the table quickly enough (I doubt this would happen though since there won't be batch inserts). Is table storage even the best tool to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to get partitions sorted by the lowest value, but maybe I am not understanding your scenario needs completely.

I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want to do out of the box, but maybe this will work for you:

**QueryRange**

You can ask the Tables service to give you the entities within a specified range. The following code would do that:

```
TableQuery rangeQuery = new TableQuery().
    Where(
    TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, lowerBound), TableOperators.And, TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, upperBound)));
```

Azure will return all entities that fit between the lowerBound and upperBound variables. If you need to sort them, you can do that by having your entities implement the `IEnumerable` interface and using a method such as `OrderBy()`.

Comment: I plan to implement a solution like this to handle the order by issue: http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/03/01/storing-windows-azure-storage-table-entities-in-descending-order/
There is one use case for this table so I'm tailoring it towards that. The case is displaying reports in their creation order. Each partition is going to be the most items that can be shown on a page. Each supported page size will be a factor of that so that no page will have to search in more than one partition. That's why I need a way to get the most recent page. Pks will be made just like row keys.